# Checking file handler before calling fclose

Tags: c, file

How can I check that when a `fclose( fHandler )` is called, there was a `fHandler = fopen(foo, "w");` prior to that? In a program there is a section that opens a file with increasing index number:

```
 char buffer[1024];
 sprintf(buffer, "./trace%d.txt", id);
 fHandler = fopen(buffer, "w");
```

and somewhere else in the code, I try to close such files.

```
 fclose(fHandler);
```

I want to check something like `if (fHandle_is_still_open)` prior to `fclose()`. It seems that checking `fHandler` with `NULL` works for the existence of file which is not whant I want. How can I fix that?

UPDATE:

The reason is that, somewhere in the execution, I get this error:

```
free(): invalid pointer
```

and gdb reports:

```
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
#1  0x00007ffff5e34859 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007ffff5e9f3ee in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff5fc9285 "%s\n")
    at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:155
#3  0x00007ffff5ea747c in malloc_printerr (str=str@entry=0x7ffff5fc74ae "free(): invalid pointer")
    at malloc.c:5347
#4  0x00007ffff5ea8cac in _int_free (av=<optimized out>, p=<optimized out>, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:4173
#5  0x00007ffff5e94043 in _IO_deallocate_file (fp=0x555556ade8a0) at libioP.h:863
#6  _IO_new_fclose (fp=0x555556ade8a0) at iofclose.c:74
```

#7 is the fclose call.

Comment: Your program should **remember** what it did to the file handle / file descriptor.

Comment: Ideally `fHandler` should be set to NULL on close if there is a chance that it needs to be checked later. Is that not possible here?

Comment: @wildplasser: I would like to prevent double `fclose()` for a particular file.

Comment: Your program should **remember** that it did the first close. This could be done by storing program state in a variable  (e.g. setting the fp to NULL) and/or avoiding a code path that calls fclose() a second time.

Comment: Please see the updated post.

Comment: If you can't keep track of which files you have opened and closed, C is not a language you should be using.  C is unforgiving.

Comment: Q: How can I verify that I undressed before going to bed? A: undress a second time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to check if a `FILE*` was already closed. The safest way is to  check if `fHandler` is NULL, then set the `fHandler` to NULL directly after you call fclose.

```
if(fhandler)
{
    fclose(fHandler);
    fHandler = NULL;
}
```

Comment: This does of course require that the variable is initialized to `NULL` first.